# Как исправить 1/1 ErrorException in AboutController.php line 24: Unde?

Tags: laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use DB;

use Illuminate\Http\Response;
use Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse;

class AboutController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function show() {

        if(view()->exists('default.about')) {

            $page = DB::select("SELECT `name`,`text` FROm `pages` WHERE `alias` = :alias",['alias'=>'about']);
            return view('default.about')->withPage($page[0])->withTitle('About our company');

        }
        abort(404);
    }

}
```

Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 ErrorException in AboutController.php line 24: Undefined offset: 0

```
in AboutController.php line 24
at HandleExceptions->handleError('8', 'Undefined offset: 0', 'A:\on\OpenServer\domains\localhost\app\Http\Controllers\Admin\AboutController.php', '24', array('page' => array())) in AboutController.php line 24
at AboutController->show()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AboutController), 'show'), array()) in Controller.php line 55
at Controller->callAction('show', array()) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 44
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(AboutController), 'show') in Route.php line 189
at Route->runController() in Route.php line 144
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 653
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Mymiddleware.php line 29
at Mymiddleware->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in SubstituteBindings.php line 41
at SubstituteBindings->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 65
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 629
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 607
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 268
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 53
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 64
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 46
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 137
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 33
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 104
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 150
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 117
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
```

Comment: Вам явно написали, что тут `$page[0]` нет индекса 0. Проверяйте наличие записи перед выводом

Comment: Я все понял. Данные в таблицу не записались при посеве и они не могут взяться потому, что их нет

Comment: В любом случаи, даже если вы уверены, что данные есть, проверяйте это раз. Во вторых делайте запрос с помощью first(), вам нет смысла делать $page[0] если запись у вас так или иначе одна.